# Disable XDB tracking for specific site under multisite environment

Tags: xdb

How to disable XDB tracking for specific site under multi site environment (Sitecore 8.2)

Comment: The edits you made, changed this into a completely new question. Please just create a new post with that question instead of editing this older and closed question.

Answer (score 1):

In your site definitions configurations, you can set `enableTracking` to be false, This setting will define whether analytics tracking is enabled for a site or not.

Comment: Thanks for response, is there anyway to have separate collection databases in MongoDB for both sites configured in multi site environment.